# Trying to rotate a matrix 90 degrees but fails to work

Tags: python

```
def rotate_ninety(matrix):
    putin = []
    temporary = []
    row_size = len(matrix)
    col_size = len(matrix[0])
    ccount = col_size-1
    putin_idx = 0
    while ccount > -1:
        for i in range(row_size):
            temporary.insert(i, matrix[i][ccount])

        putin.insert(putin_idx, temporary)
        ccount = ccount -1
        temporary.clear()
        putin_idx += 1

    print(putin)
    return 0
```

So, if I had the input

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

The result should be:

```
[3,6,9]
[2,5,8]
[1,4,7]
```

However, when I print putin I get [[] [] []], an array of all empty things, which I don't understand where my logic went wrong. I know there are other more efficient ways to do this, but I don't see how my code is wrong

Comment: dear questionaire, please check my answer, too.

Comment: hi behdad, thanks for your answer :). Something like this was exactly what I was looking for, thanks for your help

Comment: You're very welcome @questionaire . If that is the answer you were looking for, I'll be so delighted if you choose it as the correct answer ✅ Cheers. 

Answer (score 2):

When you assign (append or insert) a `list` to a variable (another list), the `list object` will be assigned or appended. Since after you add the `temporary` list to the `putin` list and then clearing the `temporary`, the object that has been added just got removed ,too.
You need to add a `copy` of the `temporary` list to the `putin`, like this:

```py
import copy

def rotate_ninety(matrix):
    putin = []
    temporary = []
    row_size = len(matrix)
    col_size = len(matrix[0])
    ccount = col_size-1
    putin_idx = 0
    while ccount > -1:
        for i in range(row_size):
            temporary.append(matrix[i][ccount])
        putin.append(copy.copy(temporary))
        ccount = ccount -1
        temporary.clear()
        putin_idx += 1

    print(putin)
    return 0

matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
rotate_ninety(matrix)
```

And the result will be:
`[[3, 6, 9], [2, 5, 8], [1, 4, 7]]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simply way with numpy:

```
matrix = np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3))

rotated_90 = matrix.T[::-1]
```